# runningApplications deprecated in Mavericks, or what?

Tags: deprecated

Compiling the same project under OSX 10.8.5 and 10.9, I have found that runningApplications does not work with the same function as mentioned below:

```
-(void)killProcessesNamed:(NSString*)appName
{
for ( id app in [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications] ) 
{
    if ( [appName isEqualToString:[[app executableURL] lastPathComponent]] ) 
    {
        [app terminate];
    }
}
```

}

Looking at NSRunningApplication.h I've found this:

```
- (NSArray *)runningApplications NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_6);
```

I do not know if it is really deprecated, but I get a warnings about multiple ambiguous method found in NSRunningApplication.h and also in NSTask.h both regarding:

```
- (BOOL)terminate; // in NSRunningApplication.h
- (void)terminate; // in NSTask.h
```

therefore the warning disappears if I change terminated in forceTerminate:

```
//[app terminate];
[app forceTerminate];
```

The problem is that in Mavericks does not want to kill the process/app indicated.
To be more clear, the above warning appears only if the project is under ARC.
thanks

Comment: May be that works better: loop with  "for ( NSRunningApplication *app in …"

Comment: @DigiMonk Thanks but nothing. I wrote: for ( NSRunningApplication* app in [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications] )
    {
        if ( [appName isEqualToString:[[app executableURL] lastPathComponent]] )
        {
            [app forceTerminate];
        }
    }

Comment: Sorry your suggestion works, it was the fault of another thing. Thank you.